# RavenDB index doesnt show new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ravendb

I have a model defined as

```
public class Department
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name is required")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        [DisplayName("Active?")]            
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

i have added one record using the asp.net view. To retrieve the records i have created a simple index "`DepartmentIndex`" as

```
from dept in docs.Departments
select new {dept.Id,dept.Name}
```

To fetch the records I am using the following linq query

```
var depts = dbSession.Query<Department>("DepartmentIndex").OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

Till here everything is fine. I can see the first record I have added on my view page. But, when I start adding more records i don't see the newly added ones. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using build #133 i upgraded to #140 now, this doesn't seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB updates indexes in the background, so the results might be stale. See the documentation [here](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-stale-indexes) for more info. In the client API you need to call the function `WaitForNonStaleResults`, to do this.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work :( I changed the query to dbSession.Query<Department>("DepartmentIndex").Customize(x=>x.WaitForNonStaleResults()) hope this is the correct way?